# Unable to import 'cfg' Python

Tags: python

```
Bot Dev
├── cogs
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── economy.py
│   └── utility.py
├── cfg.py
├── main.py
```

I'm trying to use `cfg.py` inside `config.py` but when I do `import cfg` I get this error `Unable to import 'cfg'`

Comment: Try `from .. import cfg`

Comment: Now i get ` Attempted relative import beyond top-level package ` Error

Comment: maybe you should move `cfg.py` inside `cogs`. But if you want to separate `cfg.py` from `cogs` then you shouldn't import it to `config.py` but import data from `cfg.py` and use as argument in function imported from `cogs/config.py`